# Python Argeparse error

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Im writing a program where I am trying to create an argument for the program `-l` using `argeparse` where if you use `python myprog.py -l` it will list all the file sin my amazon s3 bucket.This is my code:

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import argparse

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read('tm/aws.cfg')
conn = S3Connection( config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_access_key_id' ), config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_secret_access_key' ) )
bucket = conn.get_bucket(config.get('prodAws', 'bucket'))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list",type=str, help= "Lists content of bucket name specified" , default = config.get('prodAws', 'bucket') )
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list:
    for key in bucket.list():
        print key.name
```

However when I run `python myprog.py -l` it gives me a `error: argument -l/--list: expected one argument` . It always needs some string after `-l` even if its gibberish like `ksdjhjk`. I tried adding the `nargs` to the parser.add_argument` but no use.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `type` or `nargs`, parser expects at least one argument. Use `action="store_true"` instead. Without `-l` key args.list will be False.

```
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", action="store_true", help="Lists content of bucket name specified" , default=config.get('prodAws', 'bucket'))
```

And vice versa you can use `store_false` to set `args.list` argument to True by default.